# Providing encryption and password for an IOT device over gRPC

Tags: encryption, tls, authentication, iot

I've been breaking my head over how to do this, as it doesn't seem to fit any example I could find online.

My IOT device servers will run on the client network and may be accessed over it or over the open internet (with port forwarding). the device comes with a paper-printed initial pass like a router.
the client is running a mobile app.

As I hate planned obsolescence (ie, the device should keep working even if the company shuts down), I don't want to create a dependence on any third-party auth service, so the server and the app should just establish trust between themselves.
with the initial contact assumed to be trusted.

In all the examples for gPRC auth I could find, the client should somehow have ahead of time the server public key. but as there are many devices, and I want each one to have a unique cert, I don't see how I can ship the app preloaded for the specific device the user will get.

I have come up with the following:

0. the device generates private/public key
1. an insecure grpc channel serves the public key to the client
2. the secure grpc channel is established with that key
3. the client authenticates with the initial password to use the API over the secure channel
4. client changes the password

I'm not looking for super-max security, just basic common-sense security.
the main issue I have with the typical scheme where SSL is used to authenticate vs a domain is that I don't know via what domain/address the device would be accessed.
are there any glaring problems in the scheme? or any reason it would not work?

Thanks!

Comment: How's physical security of the device?  I suggest using the Bluetooth pairing process, which normally involves a physical button push and typing in a pairing PIN code, to guide you in designing the initial setup procedure.  Besides your valid "planned obsolescence" concerns, also consider the case where the password is lost and/or the owner wants to recycle the device by performing factory reset and no longer has the initial setup password to give the new owner.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response!
the client would have easy physical access to the device. adding Bluetooth would require costly new hardware.
sry I wasn't clear, the initial password would be glued to the back of the device, and the password would be reset back to it upon factory reset, so a new owner would just repeat the same process after a factory reset.

I could add a some kind of button which would limit the time frame to open the insecure channel for pairing. but is it really a concern if the public key is shared openly?

Comment: I didn't say to add Bluetooth to the device, I suggested to study the sequence of operations and user interactions done during the Bluetooth pairing process instead of re-inventing your own.

Comment: If you're willing to rely on the fact that the "per-device unique factory password" sticker never wears away, then you could put a pretty long key string into a QR code.  Past experience, though, is that the lifetime of such stickers is inadequate.

Comment: The "some kind of button which would limit the time frame to open the insecure channel for pairing" isn't to protect against leaking the public key, it's to protect against brute-force attacks on the password.  Push the button once, get one (time-limited) attempt at pairing.  Fat-finger the password and you have to go push the button again.

Comment: I've looked into the bluetooth pairing protocol, but I'm not sure how applicable it is in my situation, as I'm bound by the API I got: gRPC, and the SSL capabilities it has. for brute-forcing, I could add a ratelimiter+global lock for x failed attempts.                     but my main issues are fitting the TLS/SSL security model to a case where I'm not sure which domain will the server lookalike. and I'm a bit of a news with SSL, so it's a steep learning curve